# How to pass the result of asynchronous operation from injected content script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension successfully executes an AJAX request on active page (not cross-origin) by injecting this content script:

```
// post.js
$.post("/login", {
    name: "blabla"
}, function (data) {
    alert("Success!");
});
```

This script is injected with `chrome.tabs.executeScript` from a popup/background page:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: '/src/assets/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'post.js'
    });
});
```

How can I pass the result of this AJAX request back into my popup or background page?

Comment: Thank you so much! is working!

Comment: @wOxxOm Think you could edit this question into shape and answer it? I think it'll be fine without pinning a duplicate onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from the callback function in the content script:

```
$.post("/login", {
    name: "blabla"
}, function (data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({results: data});
});
```

Or send the message and receive a response from the popup/background page:

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({results: data}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

And in the popup/background page declare the listener that will process the message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.results) {
        console.log('Got data, tab #%d', sender.tab ? sender.tab.id : -1, message.results);
        sendResponse({reply: "thanks"}); // optional, not required
    }
});
```

Notes:

- Only JSON-serializable objects may be passed so you can't use `dataType: 'xml'` parameter of `$.post` or `$.ajax` because the response in that case is a non-JSON-serializable `Document`. Use `dataType: 'html'` instead and convert it to a `Document` upon receiving in the listener.
- When injecting the content script from an extension toolbar popup beware the popup may be closed by the user so its event listeners will be destroyed and the message will be lost. This is not a problem when using a background page to receive the message.